# Short story ID: Alternate universe with Bermuda Triangle debris

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A crew in a spaceship in this universe see themselves in another ship in an alternate universe. The other universe is also filled with  objects, ships and planes that went missing at the Bermuda triangle

Comment: I highly advise going through the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) (you'll get a badge out of it) and running through the [story-identification entry](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) to get a list of clarifying questions. Edit in the answers to as many as you can to help us help you.

Comment: The Bermuda Triangle is a fairly common plot element in science fiction stories. Is there anything else memorable about the story? When did you read it? Was the main character male or female? Did you read this in paperback or hard cover? Are there aliens involved, and how alien were they?

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible that what you're thinking of is actually a novel and you're remembering part of it? *[Into the Alternate Universe](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18757042-into-the-alternate-universe)* by Bertram Chandler involves a spaceship going to another universe "empty but for the frozen remains of ancient seagoing vessels, aeroplanes and spaceships."

It's an extension of [Charles Fort](http://www.resologist.net/damn07.htm)'s "[Super-Sargasso Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Sargasso_Sea)" concept.

Comment: That book was my first thought as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is a story called "Unscheduled Flight" by Juanita Coulson that has some of these elements.  It's not on a spaceship but a regular airplane, but does have the Bermuda Triangle serving as a (one-way) gateway to an alternate Earth.  There were so many of them that they formed a rebel group called "The Triangulans".   https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?97866